# C# (how can I make a) FOR loop miss out creation of 1 object from an array if a condition isn't met

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

As the title suggests, I want to NOT create a particular instance of "FillRectangle"
if the corresponding condition in the array "isBrickLive[]" is not met...

I basically want to stop drawing the object as soon as the object live is set to false (and for the FOR loop to skip making that particular object out of an array of objects).

I have this code currently...

```
for (int b = 0, c = 0; c < brickLiveL1.Length; b++, c++)
{
    court.FillRectangle(brickColourL1[c], brickSizeLocL1[b, 2], brickSizeLocL1[b, 3], brickSizeLocL1[b, 0], brickSizeLocL1[b, 1]);
}
```

how can I do this? Can I nest FOR loops or put in an IF statement?

Comment: Check `break` statement @ : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx

Comment: how about an if with a continue?

Comment: Do you need to stop executing the loop at all or skip one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `break` if you need to stop executing the loop when your condition is met.

```
for (int b = 0, c = 0; c < brickLiveL1.Length; b++, c++)
{
    if (your condition is met) 
    {
         break;
    }
    court.FillRectangle(brickColourL1[c], brickSizeLocL1[b, 2], brickSizeLocL1[b, 3], brickSizeLocL1[b, 0], brickSizeLocL1[b, 1]);
}
```

If you want just to skip one or more loop iterations than use `continue`.

```
for (int b = 0, c = 0; c < brickLiveL1.Length; b++, c++)
{
    if (your condition is met) 
    {
         continue;
    }
    court.FillRectangle(brickColourL1[c], brickSizeLocL1[b, 2], brickSizeLocL1[b, 3], brickSizeLocL1[b, 0], brickSizeLocL1[b, 1]);
}
```

Comment: The question seems to ask for how to *skip* an element, which implies that the loop should continue. Using a break terminates the loop.

Comment: @TiesonT. well, it's hard to get what the author wants, but as I understand from `and for the FOR loop to skip making that particular object out of an array of objects` he wants to break the loop. Anyway, more comments from the author will clarify the matter

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yes, I'm sorry for the confusion. I am quite new to C# and I may have used the wrong wording to explain my intentions.

I was just wanting to `continue;` the loop. Thanks for your help guys!